# Recieve JSON Object with 2 Arrays

Tags: java, android, json

im literally new at working with JSON and I have a problem with my Web Service. With normal JSON Objects i no problems. I want to get two Arrays from the Web Service (String and Integer), so i tried to put them into two JSON Array´s and this two into a JSON Object. Now i want them to get into my Android application, but im just getting errors.

```
public static String constructJSON(Integer[] array, String[] array2) {
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    try {
    JSONObject firstArray = new JSONObject();
    firstArray.put("array0", array[0]);
    firstArray.put("array1", array[1]);
    firstArray.put("array2", array[2]);
    firstArray.put("array3", array[3]);
    firstArray.put("array4", array[4]);


    JSONObject secondArray = new JSONObject();
    secondArray.put("sArray0", array2[0]);
    secondArray.put("sArray1", array2[1]);
    secondArray.put("sArray2", array2[2]);
    secondArray.put("sArray3", array2[3]);
    secondArray.put("sArray4", array2[4]);

    JSONArray JArr = new JSONArray();
    JArr.put(firstArray);
    JArr.put(secondArray);

    mainObj.put("arrays", JArr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    return mainObj.toString();
}
```

And now the method in Android Studio:

```
private void getBW(String krankheit) {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("krankheit", krankheit);
        // Invoke RESTful Web Service with Http parameters
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try {
                    // JSON Object
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray firstJsonArr= obj.getJSONArray("array1");
                    JSONArray secondJsonArr= obj.getJSONArray("array2");
                    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        Bewertung1[k] = (Integer) firstJsonArr.get(k);

                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        medikament[j] = (String) secondJsonArr.get(j);

                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


            }
        });

        }
```

I tried different solution´s, but none of them worked for me. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You are returning `mainObj` but never actually put anything in it.

Comment: i don't quite get what's the json you want to get in the end , something like {"firstArr",[2,3,5,6];"secondArr",["dfs","sdf","dfs"]}  ?

Comment: And you are putting the arrays in two json objects which you put in an array. this doesn't sound logical to me. it sounds more logical to put the first array in one array, the second in another and put those two arrays in `mainObj`

Comment: @Ivo Beckers I did the same try catch with the other JSON Object method, with im returning them and they was filled even with try/catch

Comment: @yanivtwin yes exactly, i want to fill Bewertung1 and medikament with those 5 variable (one Integer, one String)

Comment: @Ivo Beckers i tried to put the first in one array and so on, but still got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for android. Its provides simple function to parse from and to json object. 
Have a look at this library : https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1):

You switched your function istead of what you wanted it does [{}{}]

Try this:

```
public static String constructJSON(Integer[] array, String[] array2) {
    try {
    JSONArray firstArray = new JSONArray ();
    firstArray.put( array[0]);
    firstArray.put( array[1]);
    firstArray.put( array[2]);
    firstArray.put( array[3]);
    firstArray.put( array[4]);


    JSONArray secondArray = new JSONArray ();
    secondArray.put(array2[0]);
    secondArray.put( array2[1]);
    secondArray.put( array2[2]);
    secondArray.put( array2[3]);
    secondArray.put( array2[4]);

    JSONObject JArr = new JSONObject();
    JArr.put("firstArr",firstArray);
    JArr.put("secondArr", secondArray);
    return JArr.toString();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
     return null;
}
```

this will give you the JSon you wanted , and this is the main code to use it:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray firstJsonArr= obj.getJSONArray("firstArr");
JSONArray secondJsonArr= obj.getJSONArray("secondArr");
for (int k = 0; k < firstJsonArr.size(); k++) {
    Log.e("item "+k,"item data : "+firstJsonArr.get(k));
}
for (int j = 0; j < secondJsonArr.size(); j++) {
    Log.e("item "+j,"item data : "+secondJsonArr.get(j));
}
```

this is good for practices but later you should use a library that does these type of things for you like Gson etc...

Comment: If i do it like that it can´t resolve "JArr" because its outside of try/catch.

Comment: I think my problem is in Adroind Studio, where i dont response it correctly... not sure but it still doesn´t work

Comment: instert the return into the try section , after the ctatch return null

Comment: yeah, but im not quite sure how to access the variable inside of the array´s. For example i want to get the value´s of "firstArr" (array[0], array[1]...] in Android studio, so how do i do this? Like the code i wrote at my first post above?

Comment: check update , i added the main code , where response is the function we made before

Comment: I tested the code in the web Service with the url and putting example value and it worked. So the only problem left is in Android Studio, how to access the Array´s

Comment: check the app code(android studio) i added , should work now

Comment: First thank you for your help, already helped me alot to understand the issue. But it still doesnt work in android and i dont understand why you added the Log.e method. Tried with and without the Log.e method. I will update my code above how i have it now.

Comment: no problem . the Log.e is for printing in the android monitor (at the bottom of the android studio ) you can see it there , you should see any problem in there , maybe it's internet permision in the android studio

Comment: It shouldn´t be the permission, i already recieved JSON Objects from the Web Service and also could successful use the value´s of it. Can you look please to my updated code if there is a logic issue?

Comment: Simply print the result like Log.e("response",response); andyou can see the json itself , or use www.hurl.it and call the webservice and check the json there , how do you make the webservice call

Comment: It´s always giving me an Nullpointerexception as i found out. Maybe im accessing one value to much or less.

Comment: If im using the http url and putting in the value, im recieving 2 arrays filled with 5 values i need in my browser

Comment: show the line that's giving you nullpointer , maybe it's some other problem

Comment: bewertungList.add(new Bewertung(medikament[0], Bewertung1[0].toString()));                                                                                      Its the first line where i want to add a list element into a list, but it seems both array´s are empty, after i tried to fill them with values of the code above

Comment: {"array1":[5,8,6,3,7],"array2":["paratest","Zelepho500","Paraze120","TelegeXXX","kaletra200"]}                              thats  the 2 Array im getting from the JSON Array

Comment: use debug mode in android studio and check if the json comes correctly and if the two fors work fine , someone is tripping and it could be a bad string somewhere so do use the debug mode -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4

Comment: I edited the code so you can see the full method. I Debugged it also, but if i saw right, the code after "onSuccess" gets skiped over if i use the method getBW. But i already used "onSuccess" method without calling it explicit and it worked. I dont understand it

Comment: it's hard seeing half the code and finding the answers , did you instanciate both Bewertung1 & medikament  like medikament = new String[size] ? if not they will cause a null exception

Comment: Yes I did. But i dont see anything necessary you need to see more there. The rest is just to get the entered name of the String "krankheit" for params and putting the recieved arrays into a List. But interesting fact, If i fill the 2 Arrays with random values before i do the JSON request, the values doesnt change and the programm runs as it should(but wrong values). It doesnt even put "null" into the Arrays, so its like it skips the part after "onSuccess".

Comment: You must add breakpoints in the onSuccess , you have a try and catch there so probably one of the first three lines crash and moves you to the catch , but you have to debug and see which line , if you know where the problem is , you're half way there

Comment: If i add there a breakboint its never getting accessed before the Nullpointer exception.